# How to make a colored filled box and text widget inline?

Tags: flutter

I want to bring below image design in my app using flutter. I am using container and row widget to bring them inline.But didn't work. How can i bring them inline both the color filled box and the text?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just surround your [Row](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) widgets with an additional `Row`. On the outer `Row` you then can set `MainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`or `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. This creates the spacing between the different options.

Below a standalone example:

[image: GUI Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
            ColoredBox(color: Colors.grey, text: 'Booked'),
            ColoredBox(color: Colors.green, text: 'Available'),
            ColoredBox(color: Colors.red, text: 'Selected'),
          ],),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColoredBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;

  ColoredBox({this.text, this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 10.0,
        height: 10.0,
        color: this.color,
      ),
      Text(this.text)
    ],);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @Niklas. I needed the space. **MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround** worked smoothly.

Comment: @Juthi Sarker Aka, Glad to help you. I would appreciate an upvote and accept. Thanks!